# C8051f312 microcontroller

Tags: c, debugging, microcontroller, 8051

I'm not very good at C language, but I have write a very simple code to a C8051F312 microcontroller.
My code doesn't working. Please help me what did I wrong.

```
#include C8051F310.h
#include stdio.h

sbit LED_16 = P1^7; // green LED: 1 = ON; 0 = OFF

void init(void)
{   
    // XBRN registers_init
    XBR0 = 0x00; 
    XBR1 = 0x00; // Enable the crossbar
    PCA0MD  = 0X00;


    // port_init
    P0MDOUT = 0x00; // Output configuration for P0
    P1MDOUT = 0x40; // Output configuration for P1
    P2MDOUT = 0x00; // Output configuration for P2
    P3MDOUT = 0x00; // Output configuration for P3
}

void main(void)
{
    init();

    while (1)
    {
        LED_16 = 1; // LED continuously illuminated
    }
}
```

Comment: *How* isn't the code working? What's the expected result? What is the actual result? Are you sure you want to use the XOR operation in the initialization of `LED_16`?

Comment: Please post the *actual* code, not an approximation of it - the above code doesn't even compile.

Comment: p1^7 is not an XOR operation it declarates the 7. bit of the P1 port (which is a led) and I want to turn on the led. and its the actual code...

Comment: Are you claiming that this code actually *compiles* ? I seriously doubt that. Just look at the #includes for starters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is Keil compiler's notation

Comment: If you're using a non-standard C dialect then you should state this in the question and tag appropriately, otherwise you'll just waste people's time

Comment: I obviously used < and > in the includes but the text editor here deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.First of all you should use one of 2 following options for `#include` directive

```
#include  "path-spec"
#include  <path-spec>
```

, not `#include path-spec`, as you did

2.To configuire 7th bit of P1 general I/O port to work in push-pull mode you should set

`P1MDOUT = 0x80;`

, not

`P1MDOUT = 0x40;`